# How to scan all sheet cells

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I want to scan excel sheet cells using `win32com` for `python` and save a dictionary of cells location and their values.

Is there an efficient way to scan a sheet ? Meaning, scan as less cells as possible but still scan all cells with data/value and ignore far away cells.

I used to use `openpyxl`, and it had a parameter of `self.max_row` and `self.max_column` for each sheet. Is there a similar parameter or a good way to calculate them ?

Comment: I used to use openpyxl, and it had a parameter of `self.max_row` and `self.max_column ` for each sheet. Is there a similar parameter or a good way to calculate them ?

Comment: Why don't you just use `openpyxl`?

Comment: It doesn't keep the workbook validators and images. Also it doesn't support insert new lines and it is very difficult to update the excel formulas when adding new line manullay using `openpyxl`.

Answer (score 1):

How about trying something like this...

```
end_row = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
end_column = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
```

If you have a very large range you plan on going through, I would suggest 
trying to minimize the back and forth through the COM layers by taking a 
range of cells into Python all at once.

I documented some of the things I ran into a while back [here](http://corylutton.com/Excel_and_COM_using_python.html).

The main tips from my prior writing:

```
# Take many values at once rather than reading each individually
end_num = sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count
col_a = sh.Range(xl.Cells(1, 1), xl.Cells(end_num, 1)).Value

# The magic numbers to turn calculation on and off
xlCalculationManual = -4135
xlCalculationAutomatic = -4105

# Turn calculation to manual
xl.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

# Turn screen updating off
xl.ScreenUpdating = False

# RUN YOUR CODE HERE #

# Turn things back on when done
xl.ScreenUpdating = True
xl.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Comment: I used 
`last_col = xlApp.ActiveCell.SpecialCells(constants.xlLastCell).Column`
`last_row = xlApp.ActiveCell.SpecialCells(constants.xlLastCell).Row`
for getting the last cell.
I will take the advice for taking a range of cells into python

Comment: Note you can use the technique mentioned in my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290216/error-xlprimary-not-defined-in-python-win32com/23306850#23306850 to import the constants